# getting error ruby - undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass in my code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, oop

I am new to ruby and practicing OOP. when i try to create an instance of JellyBean classs ('j' in my code) i am getting the error shown below.
I want to set the name attribute of j to be "vanilla jelly bean" -> (i.e @flavour + ' jelly bean')
can anybody please tell my mistake?

```
class Dessert
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :calories
  def initialize(name, calories)
    @name = name
    @calories = calories
  end
  def healthy?
    @calories < 200
  end
  def delicious?
    true
  end
end

class JellyBean < Dessert
  attr_accessor :flavour
  def initialize(flavor)
    @calories = 5
    @flavour = flavour
    @name = @flavour + ' jelly bean'
  end
  def delicious?
    @flavour != 'licorice'
  end
end

j = JellyBean.new('vanilla')
```

I am getting the following error

```
(eval):304: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from (eval):311:in `new'
    from (eval):311
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you have a typo in your initialize method:

```
def initialize(flavor)
  @calories = 5
  @flavour = flavour
  @name = @flavour + ' jelly bean'
end
```

`flavour` is declared as an attribute but never set, so is always nil. That means that `@flavour` will always be set to nil.

should be:

```
def initialize(flavour)
  @calories = 5
  @flavour = flavour
  @name = @flavour + ' jelly bean'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I run your code and put an inspect at the bottom it works:

```
#<JellyBean:0x00000001920f58 @calories=5, @flavour="vanilla", @name="vanilla jelly bean">
```

This is the line I added:

```
puts j.inspect·
```